# Are there any Live CDs (ISOs) that come with Powershell?

Tags: livecd, powershell

It seems to me that the license surrounding Powershell would prevent a Live CD coming with Powershell; but I'm not a laywer.

But it also seems to me that it would be somewhat useful for purposes of the analysis of Malware and such;

A forever air-gapped machine could be used to see what it does without unleashing it on the network.

Comment: I've never seen a single Linux distro including PowerShell by default.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yeah that was my thought; and I bet it's a licensing thing, but I'm not sure; I guess you could always create your own distro and include it for just that purpose.

Comment: Have a look into [powershell empire](https://github.com/BC-SECURITY/Empire/)

Comment: Why do you expect that [the MIT licence](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) would prevent inclusion of software on a live CD image?

Comment: license has nothing to do with this. Ubuntu contains [packages in various license by default, as long as they're free](https://askubuntu.com/q/219/253474), for example bsdextrautils and bsdmainutils are installed by default. Many distros even allow the inclusion of closed-source packages like NVIDIA drivers. However powershell isn't quite popular on Linux so that's why no distro includes it by default. Besides people on [unix.se] seem very averse to MS products and answers regarding powershell are very quickly downvoted without even known/care that they run on \*nix